# Is there a way to scan a text file with a matrix of uneven dimensions and store in a 2d array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, file

I've been trying to write a c program that is able to read the following text file of integer values and store them in a 2d array

7 11 14 12 8 4
10 12 3 4
8 0 54 21 45 11 9 10

However, the problem is that the matrix does not have uniform dimensions, so I'm having trouble with being able to express it in a 2d array that does have uniform dimensions.

I at first thought about initializing a 3x8 2d array to where each value in the cell is zero so that way when filling the array during the scanning of the txt file, any rows with less columns than intended will have each of their empty cells filled with a 0.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

   
   #define ROWS 3
   #define COLS 8 
   
  int main() 
  { 
        int a[ROWS][COLS]={ 0 }; 
        int i, j; 
         
          FILE *in; 
          in= fopen("data.txt", "r"); 
           
           for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++){ 
               for(j=0; j<COLS; j++){ 
                   fscanf(in,"%d", &a[i][j]);  
               } 
           } 
           fclose(in); 
        for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++){ 
        for(j=0; j<COLS; j++){  
            printf("%d  ", a[i][j]); 
        }   
        printf("\n");
        }
   return 0;    
  }
```

But instead of getting the intended output, which is:

```
7 11 14 12 8 4 0 0 
10 12 3 4 0 0 0 0
8 0 54 21 45 11 9 10
```

The compiler merges values from two adjacent rows to satisfy the column requirements instead rather than adding zeroes at the end of the first line and moving on to the next.

```
7 11 14 12 8 4 10 12 
3 4 8 0 54 21 45 11
9 10 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is it even possible to do something like this in c in the first place?

Comment: Try using `fgets()` to read in each 'row' one at a time. Then, use `sscanf()` inside the inner loop to assign as many values, one by one, as are found in the current row... Give that a try... (Check the return code from `sscanf()` to know that it has found 1 decimal value.)

Answer (score 0):

OP: *Is it even possible to do something **like this** (...) ?*

Below I give **a** possible way to do what you want, how you coded it. The approach is reading the seperator between the values as a single char. If this char is a newline character, it reached the end of the input line and it will break out of the "row" loop (j).

Adjusted OP code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 8

int main()
{
        int a[ROWS][COLS]={ 0 };
        int i, j;

        FILE *in;
        in= fopen("data.txt", "r");
        if ( in == NULL ) return 1;

        for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
                for(j=0; j<COLS; j++){
                        // for capturing a single seperator char
                        char capt=0;

                        // capture also a char for either space or newline
                        int r=fscanf(in,"%d%c", &a[i][j], &capt);

                        // if newline detected ( unix  or  dos )
                        // break out of the for j loop
                        if ( capt == 0xa || capt == 0xd ) break;
                }
        }
        fclose(in);
        for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
                for(j=0; j<COLS; j++){
                        printf("%d  ", a[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

OP: *Is there a better way to do this?*

I am sure that there are many different ways that are better than my example, and I would believe a number of them can be found here on stackoverflow.com.

Good Luck